# Why is Scala Future running sequentially when mapped over an Iterator

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, iterator, future

So I am puzzled why mapping over an iterator with Futures will make it run sequentially. Consider the following code -

```
import org.scalameter._

object IteratorVsListInFutures extends App {
  def slowFunction = Thread.sleep(1000)

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  import scala.concurrent._
  import duration._

  println("Should take approximately 4000 ms or 4 sec")
  println{
    withWarmer(new Warmer.Default) measure {
      List(1,2,3,4).foreach(_ => slowFunction)
    }
  }

  println("Should take approximately 1 second")
  println {
    withWarmer(new Warmer.Default) measure {
      val futures: Seq[Future[Unit]] = List(1,2,3,4).map(_ => Future { slowFunction})
      futures.foreach(x => Await.result(x, 10.seconds))
    }
  }

  println("And how long does this take")
  println {
    withWarmer(new Warmer.Default) measure {
      val futures = List(1,2,3,4).iterator.map(_ => Future { slowFunction})
      futures.foreach(x => Await.result(x, 10.seconds))
    }
  }

}
```

I get the following results -

```
Should take approximately 4000 ms or 4 sec
4012.132085 ms
Should take approximately 1 second
1004.997573 ms
And how long does this take
4016.533206 ms

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The first benchmark is as predicted about 4 seconds, the second benchmark is also as predicted about 1 second (because the futures are executed in parallel) 
What confuses me is why the 3rd benchmark is about 4 seconds too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to [non-strict](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2017/11/28/view-based-collections.html#background-lazy-vs-strict-collections) nature of iterators the following

```
List(1,2,3,4).iterator.map(_ => Future { slowFunction })
```

evaluates to `Iterator[Future[Unit]]` which is just a **description** of transformations to happen, but have not happened yet. The key is to understand

> lazy collections are particularly useful to describe successive
>   transformation operations **without evaluating intermediate
>   transformations**

Let us rewrite your example slightly to emphasise the intermediate transformation

```
List(1,2,3,4)
  .iterator
  .map(_ => Future { slowFunction })         // <-- intermediate transformation
  .foreach(x => Await.result(x, 10.seconds))
```

Thus `map(_ => Future { slowFunction })` is the intermediate transformation that does not get evaluated, however this is the transformation that was supposed to kick-off futures. Instead, the `map` transformation is combined with `foreach` transformation to be executed as one single transformation like so

```
 List(1,2,3,4)
   .foreach(_ => Await.result(Future { slowFunction }, 10.seconds) )
```

Now it becomes clear that we are awaiting the completion of the `Future` before we move on to the next element, hence `Future`s complete serially.